# custom fields wordpress

Tags: php, html

I am trying to add a value assigned in the custom field by doing a post in these following steps: I make a new post, add a new custom field where i specify a name and a value.

**PHP**

I add the following scripts to index.php loop exactly below where the **while** and its parameter begins and to the HTML where I want the field added respectively

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_meta();?>


<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'key');?>
```

The hard part for me to understand if i am doing right is the HTML. when i launch the site using firefox and firebug, I detect the post and find the html where the field is supposed to be added. But I noticed that WP automatically generates paragraph tags for the original post, so i honestly dont know where i am supposed to add the get_post_meta for it to be added into my post.

Comment: Wordpress questions fit better here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you please rephrase it? probably with an example. All I can guess is you dont want <p> tags in post data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, this will remove your paragraph tag,

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php echo get_the_Content(); ?>
    <div class="custom-field">
        <?php $customfield = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'key'); echo $customfield[0];?>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>`
```